# In Gunnerkrigg Court, what happened to the seeds that Ysengrin dropped?

Tags: fantasy-genre, webcomics, gunnerkrigg-court

When Coyote and Ysengrin meet with the Court to discuss the fallen tik-tok bird, Ysengrin drops several seeds when he attacks Annie. The headmaster and Jones declare the entire meeting to have been a transparent ruse to drop those seeds. But as we learn more about Gillitie Forest, there hasn't been much that Coyote and Ysengrin WANT from the Court, and I don't recall the seeds ever being mentioned again. Have we been given any hints about a) what happened to those seeds, b) what they were, or c) what Ysengrin was trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well, in Chapter 66 seeds resurfaced in rather surprising manner. After being stored in Court for years, they were finally used against the Court.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think any of your questions have been answered explicitly yet.

I assume that Ysengrim was trying to spy on the court ([as he or the forest seems to have done before](http://www.gunnerkrigg.com/archive_page.php?comicID=550)), and that the seeds have been moved to the [decontamination habitat](http://www.gunnerkrigg.com/archive_page.php?comicID=88) as explained [here](http://www.gunnerkrigg.com/archive_page.php?comicID=609).

Comment: Interesting! I bet you're right, and that's where the seeds ended up. They're not the tree in the last panel though - that's the enchanted arm that caused Robot to knock Annie off the bridge. You can still see the hand shape at the center.

Comment: @abcooper: Right! Ok, I'll edit my answer.